# How do I update row positions with a form in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table of categories that have a "position" field.  The results will be ordered by this field.  I want to be able to select a position (other than last) for the new row.

Basically, the form has a field that lets a user select "Before" or "After", and then lists all the categories by position.  Once the form is submitted, it should update the form based on the selection.  For example, if there are 7 existing rows and the user selects "Before 5" it should give the new row the position of 5 and then update every row after that (including the row that previously was position 5).  If "After 5" is selected, the new row will be given a position of 6 and rows that were previously 6 and 7 will be updated to 7 and 8.

Anyone have any ideas?

PS:  I'm doing this in CodeIgniter (if you couldn't tell), but I'm pretty sure the logic will be basically the same.

```
if(count($this->info) > 0)
{       
     if($this->info['place'] == 0)
     {            
          $new_cat_position = $this->info['where'];       
     }
     else
     {       
          $new_cat_position = $this->info['where'] + 1;
     }
     $data = array(
            'title' => $this->info['title'],
            'collapsible' => $this->info['collapsible'],
            'position' => $new_cat_position
        );
     if($this->db->insert('forum_parents', $data))
     {
          if($this->info['place'] == 0)
          {
              $this->db->where('position > ', $new_cat_position + 1);
          }
          else
          {
              $this->db->where('position > ', $new_cat_position);
          }
          if(!$this->db->update('forum_parents', $data))
          {
              $this->error = "The category was created, however, the positions of the other categories were not updated correctly... ".$this->db->_error_message();
          }
     }
     else
     {
          $this->error = "An unknown system error occurred while processing your request.  Please try again later... ".$this->db->_error_message();
     }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code at least of what have you tried.

Comment: ^^^ Done!  PS:  I'm doing this in CodeIgniter, if you couldn't tell... lol.  But the logic should be pretty much the same.

Comment: That's the complete opposite of what I want to do.  The whole point is to reorder positions.  If I am creating a new category, and I want to put it before a category thats already there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataTable. It will help you. In that try row-reordering function as per your requirement.

Here is the link :

```
 http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index
```

Here is the Working Example:

```
 http://live.datatables.net/onigip/2
```

Once you are able to Roe-Reordering, You can update that records in your database using some logic.

Hope this help.